# Subtracting Time from a datetime

Tags: c#, linq

Im having a tough time with a query i'm trying to make. I have a some files I want to open with the name -

> XX-20160229-0920

(each file has a different time). I need to open the files that only match the currentTime minus a couple of hours. The hours I subtract are different each time. I've tried using `currentTime.AddHours(time)` but if The number of hours im subtracting is bigger than the current time the date won't change accordingly which is something I need to parse with the file name.

Comment: Please add some code; I suggest writing a comparison for the dates to be accepted, which is then generalized to accept or reject certain file names.

Comment: This is not a datetime. It can be a string instead. Have you ever try to parse it first? Is it always `XX-yyyyMMdd-HHmm` format?

Comment: I know what to compare, I just need a way to substract hours and for the date to update accordingly

And yes- I can't change the file name. It will always be the same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var name = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2)
    .ToString("XX-yyyyMMdd-hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This will give you the date/time in your requested format, but obviously this will change every minute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by first defining a conversion from the filenames to actual datetime values; in total, the following function can accept or reject the date, based on some comparison value.

```
bool AcceptFileName(string FileName, DateTime Now, int HoursIntoPast)
{
    DateTime DateTimeFromFileName
        = DateTime ParseExact(FileName, "XX-yyyyMMdd-hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return Now.AddHours(-HoursIntoPast) <= Now;
}
```